# scripts doesn't executed after partial rendering in mvc, why?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I used mvc 4.0 to develop my web application, I have created a pager and data-list it works fine, I implement it by some jquery code and I define $.get jquery method to get a partial view as new page like this :

```
$.get("http://localhost:13824/bid/index?page=8&script=1", function(data) {
         $Element.html(data);
}
```

on the other side in control I have Action method like following :

```
public ActionResult Index(string provinceNo="21", int page=1, string script="0"){
    if(script=="1") { return PartialView("mypartialwebusercontrol",model); }
    else // do something else;
}
```

in the web user control I have some items it loads all items and my pager works very nice but there is a problem I have link in each item that is for opening a popup window when I click on pager it calls $.get method. all click events and scripts wont be rise again.

my web user control is like this :

```
<% control language="c#" inherits="system.web.mvc.viewusercontrol<model>" %>
<% foreach(var item in model) { %>
<div id="card1">
  <a class="linkbutton"> item.text1 </a>
</div>
<% } %>
```

all of the click script will be stop after $.get method calling.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly how the links in the user control trigger the $.get method, and what script is stopping when that happens?  I think that's what you're saying if not please clarify.

Comment: $(".linkButton").bind({ click : $.proxy(this.linkbuttonClick, this) }); in constructor and add function in jquery class

Comment: every scripts stop like linkbuttonclick: function(e) { alert("hi"); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what you mean by 'in constructor', but I can see two possible causes of the problem:

- One, you are running the bind before you load the html and consequently the linkButtons aren't bound.  Solution is to run the bind after loading, or better, use .delegate on the container you are loading into.
- Two, when the browser is running the $.get method or any javascript after that, it is hitting an error and stopping executing any more scripts.

If its neither of these, you'll need to give a full listing of your Javascript or a link to a page where me or someone else can see exactly what's going on